# Auth data is not accessible in AppServiceProvider Laravel 5.5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use App\Classes\DynamicMenu;
use App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController;
use Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
       dd(Auth::user());   
    }
}
```

This returns 'null' for me, but other controllers returns user details. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why?**

It is because, when the `boot` method of a service provider is being called, the user is not yet authenticated.

---

**Solution:**

I guess you are trying to use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers)

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers#the-boot-method):

> So, what if we need to register a view composer within our service
>   provider? This should be done within the boot method. **This method is
>   called after all other service providers have been registered**, meaning
>   you have access to all other services that have been registered by the
>   framework:

So you can use the following:

```
public function boot(Guard $auth) {
    view()->composer('*', function($view) use ($auth) {
        $user = $auth->user();

        // other application logic...

        $view->with('currentUser', $user);
    });
}
```

Comment: how I can achieve same when using APIs as their are not blade/view used when using Laravel API's